# php save string of bits to file

Tags: php, file, binary

I am trying to save a string of bits to a binary file.

This is my string

```
01001001010011100101000001010101010101000011000100000000000000000100100101001110010100000101010101010100001100100000000000000000010010010100111001010000010101010101010000110011000000000000000001001001010011100101000001010101010101000011010000000000000000000100100101001110010100000101010101010100001101010000000000000000010010010100111001010000010101010101010000110110000000000000000001001001010011100101000001010101010101000011011100000000000000000100100101001110010100000101010101010100001110000000000000000000010100100100010101001100010000010101100100110001000000000000000001010010010001010100110001000001010110010011001000000000000000000101001001000101010011000100000101011001001100110000000000000000010100100100010101001100010000010101100100110100000000000000000001010010010001010100110001000001010110010011010100000000000000000101001001000101010011000100000101011001001101100000000000000000010100100100010101001100010000010101100100110111000000000000000001010010010001010100110001000001010110010011100000000000000000000011000000000000001100000000000000110000000000000011000000000000001100000000000000110000000000000011000000000000001100000000000000110001001100000011000100110000001100010011000000110001001100000011000100110000001100010011000000110001001100000011000100110000001011010011001100101101001100110010110100110011001011010011001100101101001100110010110100110011001011010011001100101101001100110011001100110010001100110011001000110011001100100011001100110010001100110011001000110011001100100011001100110010001100110011001000110000000000000011000000000000001100000000000000110000000000000011000000000000001100000000000000110000000000000011000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000110000
```

And this is the code i am using to write it.

```
$fp = fopen('io2454929593', 'wb');
fwrite($fp, pack('C*', $bytes));
fclose($fp);
```

All i get i just a 1 byte long file, but it should be a lot longer. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: probably you need to implode the array in a unique string before "pack"

Comment: Looking at the PHP manual, it seems the arguments to `pack` can only be a single argument for the format (in your case C*) and then an unlimited list of arguments, each of which should consist of one byte. Try this: `pack('C*',01001001,01001110 etc)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$s = '0100100101001110'; // your binary string

$chars = array_map('bindec', str_split($s, 8));
array_unshift($chars, 'C*');
echo call_user_func_array('pack', $chars);
```

**Disclaimer**: this code just illustrates how `pack` should be called; it should not be used for large strings.

Comment: Fair enough :) though, for your example of 2048 characters it would only pass 257 arguments to pack, still no biggie IMO :D